How do I get this UI to be as needed without missing any corners?
I am still trying to find my feet in flutter and need to implement this complex shape:

How can I make a complex shapes like this?
I tried to use custom painter by first getting the flutter path of one of the widgets, but the shape is really off. I can't seem to get it right
my code:
  class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      Paint paint = Paint();
      Path path = Path();
  

      // Path number 1
  

      paint.color = Color(0xff00baa33ef);
      path = Path();
      path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.3);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.23, size.width * 0.98, size.height * 0.18, size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.18);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.18, size.width * 0.84, size.height * 0.18, size.width * 0.84, size.height * 0.18);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.82, size.height * 0.18, size.width * 0.8, size.height * 0.16, size.width * 0.79, size.height * 0.13);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.79, size.height * 0.13, size.width * 0.77, size.height * 0.06, size.width * 0.77, size.height * 0.06);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.03, size.width * 0.74, size.height * 0.01, size.width * 0.72, size.height * 0.01);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.72, size.height * 0.01, size.width * 0.07, size.height * 0.01, size.width * 0.07, size.height * 0.01);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.03, size.height * 0.01, size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.06, size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.13);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.13, size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.9, size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.9);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.96, size.width * 0.03, size.height, size.width * 0.07, size.height);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.07, size.height, size.width * 0.95, size.height, size.width * 0.95, size.height);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.98, size.height, size.width, size.height * 0.96, size.width, size.height * 0.9);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.9, size.width, size.height * 0.3, size.width, size.height * 0.3);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.3, size.width, size.height * 0.3, size.width, size.height * 0.3);
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
      return true;
    }
  }

